# Popup using JavaScript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I have created a popup when I click on hello (plane geometry) as shown in the figure, but the popup 
appears on the extreme left of the screen I don't know how to make it appear on the plane geometry box
can someone please help me how to fix this. I have also uploaded the code.

[image]

```js
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(pickables);
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    if (intersects[0].object.name === "plane")
      window.open(intersects[0].object.userData.URL);

    // alert ("plane");
    else if (intersects[0].object.name === "plane1") {
      var popup = document.getElementById('myPopup');
      popup.classList.toggle('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
/* The actual popup */

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
/* Popup arrow */

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps create a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood your code correct, you are using position absolute on the popup but not giving it any coordinates, so it is on top left of the screen

```
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; //place it where you want
  left:50%; // place it where you want
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give The z-index property to your pop-up. And Remove Position:absolute in .popup class..

Like This :

```
.popup {
position: absolute; //Remove This position
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
z-index: 999999;  // Add z-index
}
```

`Position: absolute` property specifies positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

Answer (score 0):

To display an I element **(top)** to II element **(bottom)**, you need to use **z-index** feature of CSS. Also z-indexing should be high then bottom element.

Apart from this give accurate position of your top element, means where you want to display.

So you just need to edit your CSS code like this way:

```
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 99999; // should be high to bottom element
  left: 50%; // your element aligned from left
  top: 50%; // your element aligned from top
}
```

You can change these three element as per your requirement.